# HTML in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-2

Asp.net is my first incursion into web development using server side tech. The last time I used HTML was when tables where used for rendering and CSS was a dream. I know the usual tags but I've come across some like `<form />` and `<input />`.

I haven't used these or CSS before. I am running under the impression that these are standard HTML tags and not asp.net specific, so the question is.

Is there a book that you recommend to structure HTML output using these tags and CSS?

Also anyone know of a resource to learn about GET/POST as I haven't ran into these concepts before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For books:

- [Head First HTML with CSS &
  XHTML](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101978/)
- [HTML, XHTML, and CSS All-in-One Desk
  Reference For
  Dummies](http://www.dummies.com/store/product/HTML-XHTML-and-CSS-All-in-One-Desk-Reference-For-Dummies.productCd-0470186275,navId-322456.html)

If you want to get familiar with tags quickly I can also suggest [w3school's html tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp).

Comment: to everyone suggesting w3schools - while good for beginners, be vary of them as a lot of their examples can teach bad habits. Its great as a reference but I wouldn't copy their examples for that reason.

Comment: Darko Z, what do you mean by bad habits? I am using the head first book as I like their style for introducing topics.

Answer (score 1):

a very basic online tutorial but very helpful

[HTML Forms and Input by w3schools](http://w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to learn more about ASP.net http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: Currently looking at this, there is so much information here, MS have done a great job here!